# Changing classpath in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

I recently uninstalled `jre7` and installed `jre6`, as it was required by my project. But now my program is showing an error with the classpath. How can I change the classpath in Eclipse?

The error is:

> The archive: C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_05/lib/tools.jar which is referenced by the classpath, does not exist.

Comment: You had left a reference to this jar in your project, change to the one corresponding to your jre6.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since **tools.jar** is an JDK library you can add it for all projects by configuring your Execution Environment. In **Preferences** go to **Java** > **Installed JREs** select your JDK and click on **Edit...**. In the new Dialog you can add external jars like **tools.jar** to your execution environment. I hope you have installed the JDK 1.6 and not only the JRE 1.6 as you have written in your question.

Answer (score 8):

To change the project JRE in Eclipse, you have to go into the project specific settings (select the project folder in the Package Explorer, then go in the project and then click on properties), where you will find the Java Build Path related settings.

In the Build Path section of the project settings, you have to go into the Libraries Tab:

[image]

From here, you have to double click on the JRE System Library and change the execution environment to JavaSe 1.6:

[image: JRE edit]

Answer (score 1):

Add or Edit your eclipse Classpath Variables. It is under Window > Preferences > Java > Build Path directory of eclipse.For example;

```
      JDK_HOME - C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_24
```

Comment: I also thought that it will solve the problem
But problem is somewhere else :(

Answer (score 1):

rightclick on the project -> build path -> configure build path

...then you can change the jre for the project (from jre7 to jr6 maybe) and also remove all other libs that don't exists anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Add your own classpath into eclipse :
`Project->Run/Debug Settings->Edit->Classpath`